# safe approach to convert table from MyISAM to InnoDB

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, myisam

I know running a simple query will convert the table from `MyISAM` to `InnoDB`.
Also we can move data into a table with `InnoDB`.
These two approaches are fine.
But my production database tables has almost 2 million records with active CRUD all the time by online users.

**My concert is**

- If I run the query `ALTER TABLE users ENGINE = InnoDB;` It will definitely take time, what if online users access this table during this time?

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Don't get tired @Bill

Comment: Lots of tips [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb) .  You must stop _write_ activity during the conversion; there is probably not practical way to avoid losing _some_ of the writes otherwise.